# Font corruption Ubuntu 12.04 Mirosoft Office 2007 / Google earth & Adobe

Tags: 12.04, ubuntu-font-family, crossover-office

When using MS office 2007 applications I get lines going through text fields on excel spreadsheets and also when I open or save any MS Office document.

I am using crossover to run office but I'm also using `ttf-mscorefonts` for Adobe and Google earth.

It appears that sense I upgraded to 12.04 from 11.10 the ms fonts clash.  Because if I  purge ttf all is OK on MS Office but then Adobe and Google are unreadable

Any ideas?

Thanks

Sean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i can answer my own question.

it appears that google earth conflicts with crossover when using MS Office 2007.

all i have to do to fix the issue is simply close out Google Earth and all is good.